# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python

```
import os
try: 
    os.path.exists("E:/Contact") #Check if dir exist     
except:
    os.mkdir("E:/Contact")   #if not, create

def add(name,cell,email): #add contact
    conPath0 = 'E:/Contact'
    conPath1 = '/ '
    conPath1b =  conPath1.strip()
    conPath2 = name+'.txt'
    conPath = conPath0+conPath1b+conPath2
    file = open(conPath,'w')  
    file.write('Name:'+ name+'\n') #write into file
    file.write('Cell:'+ cell+'\n')
    file.write('Email:'+ email+'\n')
    file.close()
def get(name):  #get contact
    conPath0 = 'E:/Contact'
    conPath1 = '/ '
    conPath1b =  conPath1.strip()
    conPath2 = name+'.txt'
    conPath = conPath0 + conPath1b + conPath2
    try:
         os.path.exists(conPath) #check if exist
         file = open(conPath,'r')
         getFile = file.readlines()
         print(getFile)
    except:
        print("Not Found！")
def delete(name): #delete contact
    conPath0 = 'E:/Contact'
    conPath1 = '/ '
    conPath1b =  conPath1.strip()
    conPath2 = name+'.txt'
    conPath = conPath0 + conPath1b + conPath2
    try:
         os.path.exists(conPath) 
         os.remove(conPath) 
         print(name+"has been deleted！")
    except:
        print("Not Found！")
```

When I type this:

```
add('jack','222','ds@gmail.com')
```

I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    add('jack','222','ds@gmail.com')
  File "E:/lab/t.py", line 13, in add
    file = open(conPath,'w')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:/Contact/jack.txt'
```

I have tried E:\Contact it stil does not work.
And I have ran it successfully for the first time. But no more.
I am a newbie forgive me if my code sucks. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the path does not exist, the os.path.exists call returns False rather than throwing an exception. So the first part of the code do not work as intended. Use this instead

```
if not os.path.exists("E:/Contact"):
    os.mkdir("E:/Contact")
```